# Google Api Error: releasesRolloutTrackNotAllowed: Releases in ROLLOUT track is not supported

Tags: android, fastlane, google-play-developer-api

trying to publish a APK to goole play store, get error:`Google Api Error: releasesRolloutTrackNotAllowed: Releases in ROLLOUT track is not supported. You can create a staged rollout by using a partial release in the PRODUCTION track. - Releases in ROLLOUT track is not supported. You can create a staged rollout by using a partial release in the PRODUCTION track.`

```
  # Publishes the APK in google Play.
  supply(
    track: "rollout",
    rollout: options[:rollout]
          )
```

Comment: Google has deprecated/removed the rollout track from their support! Thats the reason why you have been getting that error in rollout track!